# What exactly do they explain in introductory discrete probability distributions?

Tags: statistics

So generally in a statistics class that gets to the part of discrete probability distributions, the construction of a table and formulas for mean and variance are discussed. Then they get to special discrete probability distributions.

My question is, what do they exactly discuss in the introduction? Is it discrete probability distribution in general? Which means those formulas for mean and variance can be applied for all the special discrete probability distributions and we just don't? The special discrete probability distribution are like shortcuts  for specialized cases in order to compute values faster? I mean it is way faster than just creating a table all the time.

I see most statistics lessons discuss in this flow but they never emphasize this. Because of the structure of the lessons, it feels like the first part is a special discrete probability distribution of its own but it actually is not.

Comment: Your question seems a bit vague to me. What formulae are you talking about? Just the definition of mean and variance or what? What are special discrete distributions to you? What do you want to generalise that you worry might not adapt very well to a general setting?

Comment: Oh sorry. I mean the summation of xf(x) for mean and (x - u)^2 f(x). I just would like to know if those formulas apply for ALL discrete the probability distributions. This means the formulas per special distribution are an ADDITIONAL option but the general one can also be used. I want to know if that is the case?

Answer (score 1):

So it seems like you might now have done a lot of mathematics before now.

So you know that if $X$ is a discrete random variable with countable state space, say, $\mathbb{N}$ and probability mass function $f$, then

$$
\mathbb{E}X:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n f(n)
$$

and in case $\mathbb{E}X^2<\infty$, you can define

$$
\operatorname{Var}(X):=\mathbb{E}(X-\mathbb{E}X)^2=\mathbb{E}X^2-(\mathbb{E}X)^2
$$

The identities following the $:=$ are *definitions*. If you are asking whether these "formulae" hold more generally, you need to have another definition in mind that they should satisfy. On the other hand, given the above, the statement $\mathbb{E}(X-\mathbb{E}X)^2=\mathbb{E}X^2-(\mathbb{E}X)^2$ is a proposition that you can prove using the definition of the expectation.

In either case, yes, these are completely general definitions. If you find yourself in doubt, just ask yourself what input you need to make the definitions work and if all of said input is present, then you can certainly generalise them.

Comment: But the reason we don't use them in special distributions is because special formulas have already been created right? Like np for mean of binomial distribution and np(1-p) for variance. I have already studied some of them and just wondered, so when do we actually use the formulas in the start if everything had to be categorized to the special distributions?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean when you say "special". That $X\sim bin(n,p)$ has mean $np$ and $np(1-p)$ is simply the fact that $X=\sum_{i=1}^n B_i$ where the $B_i$ are independent $Ber(p)$-variables and *those* variables happen to have mean $p$ and variance $np(1-p)$.

Comment: I mean... I guess it depends on your part of the world. Most elementary prob & stats courses probably focus on getting students acquainted with particular distributions but the formulae for their moment structures need to be calculated at some point, no?

Comment: $f(n)$ not $f(x)$ in the first displayed formula.

Comment: Yes. You're right.

Comment: Special as in the ones that have names like geometric, binomial and etc. But I get your point.